# Python SQLite3: want to iteratively fetching rows, but code is pulling every other row

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to accomplish a very simple task:

- Create a table in SQLite
- Insert several rows
- Query a single column in the table and pull back each row

Code to create tab:

```
import sqlite3
sqlite_file = '/Users/User/Desktop/DB.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE ListIDTable(ID numeric, Day numeric, Month
numeric, MonthTxt text, Year numeric, ListID text, Quantity text)''')


values_to_insert = [
(1,16,7,"Jul",2015,"XXXXXXX1","Q2"),
(2,16,7,"Jul",2015,"XXXXXXX2","Q2"),
(3,14,7,"Jul",2015,"XXXXXXX3","Q1"),
(4,14,7,"Jul",2015,"XXXXXXX4","Q1")]     #Entries continue similarly

c.executemany("INSERT INTO ListIdTable (ID, Day, Month, MonthTxt,
Year, ListID, Quantity) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", values_to_insert)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

When I look at this table in SQLite DB Browser, everything looks fine.

Here's my code to try and query the above table:

```
import sqlite3
sqlite_file = '/Users/User/Desktop/DB.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
c = conn.cursor()

for row in c.execute('select * from ListIDTable'):
    r = c.fetchone()
    ID = r['ID']
    print (ID)
```

I should get a print out of 1, 2, 3, 4.
However, I only get 2 and 4.

My code actually uploads 100 entries to the table, but still, when I query, I only get ID printouts of even numbers (i.e. 2, 4, 6, 8 etc.).

Thanks for any advice on fixing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `fetchone` in the loop -- The loop is already fetching the values (one at a time).  If you `fetchone` while you're iterating, you'll only see half the data because the loop fetches one and then you immediately fetch the next one (without ever looking at the one that was fetched by the loop):

```
for r in c.execute('select * from ListIDTable'):
    ID = r['ID']
    print (ID)
```